# Difference between MeasureString in System.Drawing and TextMeasurer.Measure in SixLabors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.drawing, imagesharp

I have two Methods to return width of string:

**The first method is using `System.Drawing`:**

```
public static float GetTextWidth(string fontFace, float fontSize, string text)
{
   var fontx = new System.Drawing.Font(fontFace, fontSize);
   //Using a Bitmap object for frame of reference in order to get to a Graphics object
   using Bitmap b = new(1, 1);
   //Graphics object allows string measurement
   using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
   //change the units to Point
   g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;

   retrun g.MeasureString(text, fontx).Width;
}
```

the result from this method
[image]

**The second method is using `SixLabors.Fonts`**:

```
public static float GetTextWidth(string fontFace, float fontSize, string text)
{
    var font = SixLabors.Fonts.SystemFonts.CreateFont(fontFace, fontSize);
        var sizeF = TextMeasurer.Measure(text, new TextOptions(font));

        return sizeF.Width;
}
```

The result from this method :
[image]

If you compare between the images you can see that the text is going down in the second method that used `SixLabors` library and this is wrong. In the debug mode I see that the deference between the width in both are always `10`.

**My question:**
because of System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows, I have to switch to `SixLabors` but I don't understand why the width is always '10' more when I use `SixLabors`. Can anyone explain to me why and how can I solve it?

Comment: Text will only ever wrap when a wrapping length is not set when a mandatory line break exists in your input  text. Also your DPI will be different.

Comment: @JamesSouth, thanks for you answer, I didn't understand the relation between your comment and **My question** !

Comment: _If you compare between the images you can see that the text is going down in the second method that used SixLabors library and this is wrong_


I'm telling you why the text is wrapped.


_I don't understand why the width is always '10' more when I use SixLabors._


Text measurements are measured in pixels. If the DPI is different then the pixel size will be different.